# How to Generate TOC page numbers with CSS in pdf

Tags: html, css

I am using flying saucer library to convert my HTML page to PDF.
The TOC Structure in my case is.

```
  <ul id="toc">

     <li class="H2 toc-primary-nav">
        <a id="link0" href="#title0" title="H2">1. Economical multisignal meter DP20  ■ ▲ </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The TOC gets generated properly. I want page numbers of href tag for my TOC table. For which I am confused about CSS.
Whether I should use CSS this way,

```
#toc a::after { content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page); }
```

or

```
@page {#toc a::after { content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page); }}
```

or

```
@media print {#toc a::after { content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page); }}
```

Comment: have you tried using <ol> instead of <ul> ?

Comment: there resides no issue in ol or ul. The issue is where would I put that CSS in paged media or print media or as plain. @Selvam

Comment: Looking at the spec [1], have you tried to cast the `href` attribute to actual URL, i.e. `attr(href)` → `attr(href url)`? I'd suppose simple `attr` would get just string what might cause some confusion…
[1] https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#target-counter

Comment: ..ah, I see. your question after all is not _"how to make this work"_ (because it works already) but _"where to put print-specific CSS"_. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: target-counter function does not work for me. Is that because I am not using princexml? @myf

Comment: Cannot verify ATM, but from murky memory and [1] I think that Flying Saucer supports it.
[1] https://github.com/amardaxini/acts_as_flying_saucer/wiki/PDF-Bookmarks-and-TOC#table-of-content-toc

Comment: I too suppose this. But for me counter, counters almost all CSS3 functions work. Other than target-counter and target-counters. Odd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go into `@media print {}` block if

- the style element referencing given style sheet does not declare such media restriction already,
- and your use case involves scenario when given document could be viewed in other (`screen`) media, where CSS paged media extensions could not apply.

The `@page {}` block has different purpose (defines page properties) and doesn't accept selectors.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer seems acceptable to me. What about @media print{} does it accept selectors?

Comment: Sure, that's its purpose to enclose rules:
- `<style>/* universal rules */ @media print {/* print rules */} /* universal rules*/</style>`
- `<style media="print">/* print rules*/</style>`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="URI of the file with print rules" />`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you refer to the fact that given rules does not affect outcome in regular browser (which operates as `screen` agent), keep in mind that Flying Saucer as acts as a `print` agent so it should work in it.

Comment: @media print { 
/* All your print styles go here */
 
 #toc a::after { 
  content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page); 
 }

} I define many rules inside, all working very finely other than the toc one.